# Mutability of imported variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I am trying to carry changes to an imported var between files.
See example below:

file1.py

```
string = 'data1'

def change_string():
    global string
    string = 'data2'

#this does not update string in file2
change_string()
```

file2.py

```
from file1 import string

#this prints initial value of string, regardless of change_string() function called in file1
print string
```

Despite calling change_string() in file1 before printing it in file2 the value still reads 'data1.'

What am I missing here?  I am able to edit other variables (collections like dicts, etc.) over an import statement.

If I call `print string` after `change_string()` I want to print `data2`.

How do I do what I am trying to do?

Comment: I got "data2" after test.

Comment: python 2 or 3???

Comment: @MaNKuR should be Python 2. `print string ` is not allowed in Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, strings are immutable objects ;)

When you do `from file1 import string` you are bringing to your **file1.py**'s *global symbol table* the value that at the moment of the import the variable (or name) "string" on the module "file1.py" was referencing/mapping-to.

Doing this you are creating a completely new name besides in the "file2.py" module's symbol table, that point to a value that as is immutable can't be changed.

When you do:

```
global string
string = 'data2'
```

What you are doing is not changing the value of the object 'data1' (to which the name of the **file1.py** was pointing/mapped-to at), but creating a new object and re-mapping the name "string" in the **file1.py** module's symbol table to that new object, "data2" in this case.

**EDIT:**

Your code actually return 'data2' because `change_string()` is executed before finalizing the *file1.py* module imports, so before create the *string* symbol in the symbol table of module **file2.py**. I just change your code in this example to illustrate the problem that I guess you are referring to: calling the `change_string()` after the imports don't change the data.

**file1.py**

```
conf = {'string': 'data1'}

def change_string():
    global conf
    conf['string'] = 'data2'
```

**file2.py**

```
from file1 import conf, change_string

change_string()
print conf['string']
```

Comment: D'oh, I knew it was something obvious I was overlooking.

How do I make this act like I want?  Put the string in a container?

That seems like it would be excessive overhead for what I am trying to do.

Comment: Yes, you have to use a mutable object. I think that a simple dict is not that bad ;)

Comment: @stamaimer Yep, that is why I said: "Your code actually return 'data2' because change_string() is executed before finalizing the file1.py module imports".

Answer (score -1):

When you import something, you get the version of that thing at the moment you import it. Any changes made after you've imported it *will not carry over*.

The only solution (when importing a variable) is to re-import that variable after a change has been made.

You can, however, import the module itself, rather than one of its variables. This will allow you to access the variable at any time, therefore any changes made will track.

Comment: @stamaimer: Yes. It outputs `data2`.